# Personal repository address on netinstall

Tags: debian, installation

We've got a working lenny repository in our office. This is the sources.list line from a machine where the repo works fine:

```
deb http://fai.foo.com/ftp.es.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free
```

I would like to install lenny on another machine but using:

```
http://fai.foo.com/ftp.es.debian.org
```

as address and /debian/ as directory doesn't work.

Are these addresses correct? Must repo and install image be exactly the same version? (netinstall image: debian-501-i386-netinst.iso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the dists directory inside the debian folder and create a symlink to lenny as stable

```
ln -s lenny stable
```

The installer looks for stable or testing and not for lenny.

I found this looking at the apache logs when I first encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I modified /target/etc/apt/sources.list from console (and apt-get update of course) while installing and that made the trick. Anyway, it would be great to know why the elegant way didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what foo.com is, but I guess it's just something you made up? Try some of the following addresses.

http://www.debian.org/mirror/list

```
Host name            FTP               HTTP  

Spain
ftp.es.debian.org
  (ftp.gul.uc3m.es)     /debian/          /debian/  
debian.com.es         /debian/  
debian.grn.cat          /debian/          /debian/  
ftp.caliu.cat           /debian/          /debian/  
ftp.cica.es             /debian/          /debian/  
ftp.gva.es              /mirror/debian/   /mirror/debian/   
ftp.rediris.es          /debian/          /debian/  
ftp.udc.es           /debian/          /debian/     
ftp.um.es             /mirror/debian/
```

Comment: "foo" it's just an example. I cannot use a public mirror because of company's firewall. Just company's mirror.

Answer (score 0):

The mirror should be the full path to the base of the mirror. This directory should contain the "dists" folder.

So, it's basically the same thing as you'd put in your sources.list

> http://fai.foo.com/ftp.es.debian.org/debian

A quick breakdown of the sources.list URL, which is

> deb http://fai.foo.com/ftp.es.debian.org/debian lenny main contrib non-free

- deb - this means that this is a binary repository
- http://fai.foo.com/ftp.es.debian.org/debian - the URL of the repository
- lenny - the distribution that you're working with (lenny, etch, stable, unstable, etc)
- main contrib non-free - the components of Debian you wish to use

In fact, I have an old image from when I was trying to explain it to people before

http://people.debian.org/~mez/sources.list.png